# Add caret below AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

I'm trying to do what's highlighted on the image, but no luck so far.

Any suggestions on how could I do this? This raises some questions regarding the elevation, which is the main problem.

[image: Goal]

The Toolbar is set up properly and the rest (white space) will be views that are also set up inside the AppBarLayout.

Comment: You can make a [9-patch drawable](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html) to use as the background of the container.

Comment: That caret needs to be an object as it will be moved horizontally.